# Serialize protobuf message in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, protocol-buffers

***Description***

Given the following `.proto` file: https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-pbf/blob/main/proto/FeatureCollection/FeatureCollection.proto

I compiled the python version using `protoc` which resulted in the following:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Generated by the protocol buffer compiler.  DO NOT EDIT!
# source: FeatureCollection.proto
"""Generated protocol buffer code."""
from google.protobuf.internal import builder as _builder
from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
from google.protobuf import descriptor_pool as _descriptor_pool
from google.protobuf import symbol_database as _symbol_database
# @@protoc_insertion_point(imports)

_sym_db = _symbol_database.Default()

DESCRIPTOR = _descriptor_pool.Default().AddSerializedFile(b'\n\x17\x46\x65\x61tureCollection.proto\x12\x0b\x65sriPBuffer\"\xab\x1f\n\x18\x46\x65\x61tureCollectionPBuffer\x12\x0f\n\x07version\x18\x01 \x01(\t\x12\x46\n\x0bqueryResult\x18\x02 \x01(\x0b\x32\x31.esriPBuffer.FeatureCollectionPBuffer.QueryResult\x1aj\n\x10SpatialReference\x12\x0c\n\x04wkid\x18\x01 \x01(\r\x12\x13\n\x0blastestWkid\x18\x02 \x01(\r\x12\x0f\n\x07vcsWkid\x18\x03 \x01(\r\x12\x15\n\rlatestVcsWkid\x18\x04 \x01(\r\x12\x0b\n\x03wkt\x18\x05 \x01(\t\x1a\xce\x01\n\x05\x46ield\x12\x0c\n\x04name\x18\x01 \x01(\t\x12\x42\n\tfieldType\x18\x02 \x01(\x0e\x32/.esriPBuffer.FeatureCollectionPBuffer.FieldType\x12\r\n\x05\x61lias\x18\x03 \x01(\t\x12>\n\x07sqlType\x18\x04 \x01(\x0e\x32-.esriPBuffer.FeatureCollectionPBuffer.SQLType\x12\x0e\n\x06\x64omain\x18\x05 \x01(\t\x12\x14\n\x0c\x64\x65\x66\x61ultValue\x18\x06 \x01(\t\x1a\xe5\x01\n\x05Value\x12\x16\n\x0cstring_value\x18\x01 \x01(\tH\x00\x12\x15\n\x0b\x66loat_value\x18\x02 \x01(\x02H\x00\x12\x16\n\x0c\x64ouble_value\x18\x03 \x01(\x01H\x00\x12\x14\n\nsint_value\x18\x04 \x01(\x11H\x00\x12\x14\n\nuint_value\x18\x05 \x01(\rH\x00\x12\x15\n\x0bint64_value\x18\x06 \x01(\x03H\x00\x12\x16\n\x0cuint64_value\x18\x07 \x01(\x04H\x00\x12\x16\n\x0csint64_value\x18\x08 \x01(\x12H\x00\x12\x14\n\nbool_value\x18\t \x01(\x08H\x00\x42\x0c\n\nvalue_type\x1a\x33\n\x08Geometry\x12\x13\n\x07lengths\x18\x02 \x03(\rB\x02\x10\x01\x12\x12\n\x06\x63oords\x18\x03 \x03(\x12\x42\x02\x10\x01\x1a \n\x0f\x65sriShapeBuffer\x12\r\n\x05\x62ytes\x18\x01 \x01(\x0c\x1a\xb5\x02\n\x07\x46\x65\x61ture\x12?\n\nattributes\x18\x01 \x03(\x0b\x32+.esriPBuffer.FeatureCollectionPBuffer.Value\x12\x42\n\x08geometry\x18\x02 \x01(\x0b\x32..esriPBuffer.FeatureCollectionPBuffer.GeometryH\x00\x12L\n\x0bshapeBuffer\x18\x03 \x01(\x0b\x32\x35.esriPBuffer.FeatureCollectionPBuffer.esriShapeBufferH\x00\x12@\n\x08\x63\x65ntroid\x18\x04 \x01(\x0b\x32..esriPBuffer.FeatureCollectionPBuffer.GeometryB\x15\n\x13\x63ompressed_geometry\x1a\x39\n\rUniqueIdField\x12\x0c\n\x04name\x18\x01 \x01(\t\x12\x1a\n\x12isSystemMaintained\x18\x02 \x01(\x08\x1a]\n\x12GeometryProperties\x12\x1a\n\x12shapeAreaFieldName\x18\x01 \x01(\t\x12\x1c\n\x14shapeLengthFieldName\x18\x02 \x01(\t\x12\r\n\x05units\x18\x03 \x01(\t\x1a\x35\n\nServerGens\x12\x14\n\x0cminServerGen\x18\x01 \x01(\x04\x12\x11\n\tserverGen\x18\x02 \x01(\x04\x1aG\n\x05Scale\x12\x0e\n\x06xScale\x18\x01 \x01(\x01\x12\x0e\n\x06yScale\x18\x02 \x01(\x01\x12\x0e\n\x06mScale\x18\x03 \x01(\x01\x12\x0e\n\x06zScale\x18\x04 \x01(\x01\x1a[\n\tTranslate\x12\x12\n\nxTranslate\x18\x01 \x01(\x01\x12\x12\n\nyTranslate\x18\x02 \x01(\x01\x12\x12\n\nmTranslate\x18\x03 \x01(\x01\x12\x12\n\nzTranslate\x18\x04 \x01(\x01\x1a\xe7\x01\n\tTransform\x12Z\n\x15quantizeOriginPostion\x18\x01 \x01(\x0e\x32;.esriPBuffer.FeatureCollectionPBuffer.QuantizeOriginPostion\x12:\n\x05scale\x18\x02 \x01(\x0b\x32+.esriPBuffer.FeatureCollectionPBuffer.Scale\x12\x42\n\ttranslate\x18\x03 \x01(\x0b\x32/.esriPBuffer.FeatureCollectionPBuffer.Translate\x1a\x9d\x06\n\rFeatureResult\x12\x19\n\x11objectIdFieldName\x18\x01 \x01(\t\x12J\n\runiqueIdField\x18\x02 \x01(\x0b\x32\x33.esriPBuffer.FeatureCollectionPBuffer.UniqueIdField\x12\x19\n\x11globalIdFieldName\x18\x03 \x01(\t\x12\x18\n\x10geohashFieldName\x18\x04 \x01(\t\x12T\n\x12geometryProperties\x18\x05 \x01(\x0b\x32\x38.esriPBuffer.FeatureCollectionPBuffer.GeometryProperties\x12\x44\n\nserverGens\x18\x06 \x01(\x0b\x32\x30.esriPBuffer.FeatureCollectionPBuffer.ServerGens\x12H\n\x0cgeometryType\x18\x07 \x01(\x0e\x32\x32.esriPBuffer.FeatureCollectionPBuffer.GeometryType\x12P\n\x10spatialReference\x18\x08 \x01(\x0b\x32\x36.esriPBuffer.FeatureCollectionPBuffer.SpatialReference\x12\x1d\n\x15\x65xceededTransferLimit\x18\t \x01(\x08\x12\x0c\n\x04hasZ\x18\n \x01(\x08\x12\x0c\n\x04hasM\x18\x0b \x01(\x08\x12\x42\n\ttransform\x18\x0c \x01(\x0b\x32/.esriPBuffer.FeatureCollectionPBuffer.Transform\x12;\n\x06\x66ields\x18\r \x03(\x0b\x32+.esriPBuffer.FeatureCollectionPBuffer.Field\x12;\n\x06values\x18\x0e \x03(\x0b\x32+.esriPBuffer.FeatureCollectionPBuffer.Value\x12?\n\x08\x66\x65\x61tures\x18\x0f \x03(\x0b\x32-.esriPBuffer.FeatureCollectionPBuffer.Feature\x1a\x1c\n\x0b\x43ountResult\x12\r\n\x05\x63ount\x18\x01 \x01(\x04\x1a\x89\x01\n\x0fObjectIdsResult\x12\x19\n\x11objectIdFieldName\x18\x01 \x01(\t\x12\x44\n\nserverGens\x18\x02 \x01(\x0b\x32\x30.esriPBuffer.FeatureCollectionPBuffer.ServerGens\x12\x15\n\tobjectIds\x18\x03 \x03(\x04\x42\x02\x10\x01\x1a\xfc\x01\n\x0bQueryResult\x12L\n\rfeatureResult\x18\x01 \x01(\x0b\x32\x33.esriPBuffer.FeatureCollectionPBuffer.FeatureResultH\x00\x12H\n\x0b\x63ountResult\x18\x02 \x01(\x0b\x32\x31.esriPBuffer.FeatureCollectionPBuffer.CountResultH\x00\x12J\n\tidsResult\x18\x03 \x01(\x0b\x32\x35.esriPBuffer.FeatureCollectionPBuffer.ObjectIdsResultH\x00\x42\t\n\x07Results\"\xbe\x01\n\x0cGeometryType\x12\x19\n\x15\x65sriGeometryTypePoint\x10\x00\x12\x1e\n\x1a\x65sriGeometryTypeMultipoint\x10\x01\x12\x1c\n\x18\x65sriGeometryTypePolyline\x10\x02\x12\x1b\n\x17\x65sriGeometryTypePolygon\x10\x03\x12\x1e\n\x1a\x65sriGeometryTypeMultipatch\x10\x04\x12\x18\n\x14\x65sriGeometryTypeNone\x10\x7f\"\xcf\x02\n\tFieldType\x12\x1d\n\x19\x65sriFieldTypeSmallInteger\x10\x00\x12\x18\n\x14\x65sriFieldTypeInteger\x10\x01\x12\x17\n\x13\x65sriFieldTypeSingle\x10\x02\x12\x17\n\x13\x65sriFieldTypeDouble\x10\x03\x12\x17\n\x13\x65sriFieldTypeString\x10\x04\x12\x15\n\x11\x65sriFieldTypeDate\x10\x05\x12\x14\n\x10\x65sriFieldTypeOID\x10\x06\x12\x19\n\x15\x65sriFieldTypeGeometry\x10\x07\x12\x15\n\x11\x65sriFieldTypeBlob\x10\x08\x12\x17\n\x13\x65sriFieldTypeRaster\x10\t\x12\x15\n\x11\x65sriFieldTypeGUID\x10\n\x12\x19\n\x15\x65sriFieldTypeGlobalID\x10\x0b\x12\x14\n\x10\x65sriFieldTypeXML\x10\x0c\"\x8d\x04\n\x07SQLType\x12\x11\n\rsqlTypeBigInt\x10\x00\x12\x11\n\rsqlTypeBinary\x10\x01\x12\x0e\n\nsqlTypeBit\x10\x02\x12\x0f\n\x0bsqlTypeChar\x10\x03\x12\x0f\n\x0bsqlTypeDate\x10\x04\x12\x12\n\x0esqlTypeDecimal\x10\x05\x12\x11\n\rsqlTypeDouble\x10\x06\x12\x10\n\x0csqlTypeFloat\x10\x07\x12\x13\n\x0fsqlTypeGeometry\x10\x08\x12\x0f\n\x0bsqlTypeGUID\x10\t\x12\x12\n\x0esqlTypeInteger\x10\n\x12\x17\n\x13sqlTypeLongNVarchar\x10\x0b\x12\x18\n\x14sqlTypeLongVarbinary\x10\x0c\x12\x16\n\x12sqlTypeLongVarchar\x10\r\x12\x10\n\x0csqlTypeNChar\x10\x0e\x12\x13\n\x0fsqlTypeNVarchar\x10\x0f\x12\x10\n\x0csqlTypeOther\x10\x10\x12\x0f\n\x0bsqlTypeReal\x10\x11\x12\x13\n\x0fsqlTypeSmallInt\x10\x12\x12\x11\n\rsqlTypeSqlXml\x10\x13\x12\x0f\n\x0bsqlTypeTime\x10\x14\x12\x14\n\x10sqlTypeTimestamp\x10\x15\x12\x15\n\x11sqlTypeTimestamp2\x10\x16\x12\x12\n\x0esqlTypeTinyInt\x10\x17\x12\x14\n\x10sqlTypeVarbinary\x10\x18\x12\x12\n\x0esqlTypeVarchar\x10\x19\"5\n\x15QuantizeOriginPostion\x12\r\n\tupperLeft\x10\x00\x12\r\n\tlowerLeft\x10\x01\x42\x1c\n\x18\x63om.esri.arcgis.protobufH\x03\x62\x06proto3')

_builder.BuildMessageAndEnumDescriptors(DESCRIPTOR, globals())
_builder.BuildTopDescriptorsAndMessages(DESCRIPTOR, 'FeatureCollection_pb2', globals())
if _descriptor._USE_C_DESCRIPTORS == False:

  DESCRIPTOR._options = None
  DESCRIPTOR._serialized_options = b'\n\030com.esri.arcgis.protobufH\003'
  _FEATURECOLLECTIONPBUFFER_GEOMETRY.fields_by_name['lengths']._options = None
  _FEATURECOLLECTIONPBUFFER_GEOMETRY.fields_by_name['lengths']._serialized_options = b'\020\001'
  _FEATURECOLLECTIONPBUFFER_GEOMETRY.fields_by_name['coords']._options = None
  _FEATURECOLLECTIONPBUFFER_GEOMETRY.fields_by_name['coords']._serialized_options = b'\020\001'
  _FEATURECOLLECTIONPBUFFER_OBJECTIDSRESULT.fields_by_name['objectIds']._options = None
  _FEATURECOLLECTIONPBUFFER_OBJECTIDSRESULT.fields_by_name['objectIds']._serialized_options = b'\020\001'
  _FEATURECOLLECTIONPBUFFER._serialized_start=41
  _FEATURECOLLECTIONPBUFFER._serialized_end=4052
  _FEATURECOLLECTIONPBUFFER_SPATIALREFERENCE._serialized_start=158
  _FEATURECOLLECTIONPBUFFER_SPATIALREFERENCE._serialized_end=264
  _FEATURECOLLECTIONPBUFFER_FIELD._serialized_start=267
  _FEATURECOLLECTIONPBUFFER_FIELD._serialized_end=473
  _FEATURECOLLECTIONPBUFFER_VALUE._serialized_start=476
  _FEATURECOLLECTIONPBUFFER_VALUE._serialized_end=705
  _FEATURECOLLECTIONPBUFFER_GEOMETRY._serialized_start=707
  _FEATURECOLLECTIONPBUFFER_GEOMETRY._serialized_end=758
  _FEATURECOLLECTIONPBUFFER_ESRISHAPEBUFFER._serialized_start=760
  _FEATURECOLLECTIONPBUFFER_ESRISHAPEBUFFER._serialized_end=792
  _FEATURECOLLECTIONPBUFFER_FEATURE._serialized_start=795
  _FEATURECOLLECTIONPBUFFER_FEATURE._serialized_end=1104
  _FEATURECOLLECTIONPBUFFER_UNIQUEIDFIELD._serialized_start=1106
  _FEATURECOLLECTIONPBUFFER_UNIQUEIDFIELD._serialized_end=1163
  _FEATURECOLLECTIONPBUFFER_GEOMETRYPROPERTIES._serialized_start=1165
  _FEATURECOLLECTIONPBUFFER_GEOMETRYPROPERTIES._serialized_end=1258
  _FEATURECOLLECTIONPBUFFER_SERVERGENS._serialized_start=1260
  _FEATURECOLLECTIONPBUFFER_SERVERGENS._serialized_end=1313
  _FEATURECOLLECTIONPBUFFER_SCALE._serialized_start=1315
  _FEATURECOLLECTIONPBUFFER_SCALE._serialized_end=1386
  _FEATURECOLLECTIONPBUFFER_TRANSLATE._serialized_start=1388
  _FEATURECOLLECTIONPBUFFER_TRANSLATE._serialized_end=1479
  _FEATURECOLLECTIONPBUFFER_TRANSFORM._serialized_start=1482
  _FEATURECOLLECTIONPBUFFER_TRANSFORM._serialized_end=1713
  _FEATURECOLLECTIONPBUFFER_FEATURERESULT._serialized_start=1716
  _FEATURECOLLECTIONPBUFFER_FEATURERESULT._serialized_end=2513
  _FEATURECOLLECTIONPBUFFER_COUNTRESULT._serialized_start=2515
  _FEATURECOLLECTIONPBUFFER_COUNTRESULT._serialized_end=2543
  _FEATURECOLLECTIONPBUFFER_OBJECTIDSRESULT._serialized_start=2546
  _FEATURECOLLECTIONPBUFFER_OBJECTIDSRESULT._serialized_end=2683
  _FEATURECOLLECTIONPBUFFER_QUERYRESULT._serialized_start=2686
  _FEATURECOLLECTIONPBUFFER_QUERYRESULT._serialized_end=2938
  _FEATURECOLLECTIONPBUFFER_GEOMETRYTYPE._serialized_start=2941
  _FEATURECOLLECTIONPBUFFER_GEOMETRYTYPE._serialized_end=3131
  _FEATURECOLLECTIONPBUFFER_FIELDTYPE._serialized_start=3134
  _FEATURECOLLECTIONPBUFFER_FIELDTYPE._serialized_end=3469
  _FEATURECOLLECTIONPBUFFER_SQLTYPE._serialized_start=3472
  _FEATURECOLLECTIONPBUFFER_SQLTYPE._serialized_end=3997
  _FEATURECOLLECTIONPBUFFER_QUANTIZEORIGINPOSTION._serialized_start=3999
  _FEATURECOLLECTIONPBUFFER_QUANTIZEORIGINPOSTION._serialized_end=4052
# @@protoc_insertion_point(module_scope)
```

**Problem**

When trying to encode a message the pbf model doesn't seem to actually fill. Decoding a message works but the result is not correct. This is probably due to the .proto file version and queryResult attributes being mandatory for the parser, which the ParseFromString doesn't use out of the box.

However I am primarily only interested in encoding the protobuf message. From my understanding even a partially filled protobuf should return a binary, but my `print(pbf.SerializeToString())` delivers only an empty `b''`.

Printing an attribute of the protobuf class (e.g. `print(pbf.GeometryType)`) yields the following however: `<google.protobuf.internal.enum_type_wrapper.EnumTypeWrapper object at 0x7f6eb6f42d30>`

**Current code**

```
import FeatureCollection_pb2

pbf = FeatureCollection_pb2.FeatureCollectionPBuffer()

pbf.GeometryType.esriGeometryTypePolygon

pbf.Field.name = "Test"
pbf.Field.fieldType = "esriFieldTypeOID"
pbf.Field.alias = "Test"
pbf.Field.sqlType = "sqlTypeGUID"
pbf.Field.domain = None
pbf.Field.defaultValue = None
... and so on ...
print(pbf.SerializeToString())
```

**Question**

What am I doing wrong? Am I calling the right class inside my script, am I assigning the values correct...?

Comment: It looks like Field is not a variable but a message definition.

Comment: I compared this with the Google protocol buffer basics for python and they do it the same way.

Comment: Looking at the link with the definition file you have sent there is only a message definition named Field. The only variables in the FeatureCollectionPBuffer message definition are a string named "version" and an object named "queryResult". This last object is of the QueryResult type.

Comment: The curly brackets for FeatureCollectionPBuffer contain the other enums, messages etc. So I thought Field would be inside the FeatureCollectionPBuffer class.

Comment: Those are only the type definitions, not actual variables.

Comment: So the .proto file is faulty and I cannot use it to encode a message as stated by the developers? see: https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-pbf/tree/main/proto/FeatureCollection